# Windows 10 - Your phone - Add a phone - Disabled

Tags: mobile-phone, windows-10-v1809

I am on Windows 10 Version 1809 Build 17763.316.  I opened the `Your phone` settings page (click on `Start Menu` > `Cog` (Settings) > `Phone`).  The `Add a phone` + button is greyed out.  A message in red says `Some settings are hidden or managed by your organization` (see image below).  How do I enable the `Add a phone` + button?

[image: Your phone settings page]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The grayed-out settings is not the place to go.  You are looking for a Windows *app*.

1. Type "Phone" in the Windows menu
2. open the (windows inbuilt) Phone app
3. It will ask your phone number
4. Wait for the SMS (it will send you a link to download the "companion" app for your phone, you probably could just install it)
5. install the "companion" app on your phone
6. Scan the QR code (or just login with your windows ID)

[image]

Comment: Thanks!  The first step was all I needed.  The rest of the steps did not match but the on-screen information was enough for me to figure it out.

Answer (score 3):

I have the exact same issue. I found this: 
https://www.reddit.com/r/Windows10/comments/9pdie4/gpo_that_blocks_access_to_link_phone_in_1809/

Depending on your version of Windows 10, you can either:

1. Edit the local Group Policy (i.e. gpedit.msc) to *disable* `Turn off Microsoft consumer experiences` in `Computer Configuration -> Administrative Templates -> Windows Components -> Cloud Content` (I would also set the User Config local GP the same way) or...
2. Edit the `DisableWindowsConsumerFeatures` DWORD registry key (set it to 0): `Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\CloudContent`

Comment: I set the local group policy.  I could not find the user config local group policy.  The add a phone option is stilled grayed out.  I also set the registry key.  The add a phone option is stilled grayed out.  I rebooted.  The add a phone option is stilled grayed out.  Sadly, this answer does not work for me.

Comment: Option 1 above worked for me without a restart. The registry key mentioned in option 2 did not already exist so I didn't create it. I assume therefore there are several ways in which this feature can end up disabled, so the answer will work for some and not others.